# How to convert multiple floats in a string to multiple floats? (sscanf)

Tags: c++, type-conversion

Easy understanding:

```
string=" 2.34 5.21 7.22\n";
```

I want to get the floats of the string to float variables:

```
float x,y,z;
sscanf(string, " %f %f %f\n",&x,&y,&z);
```

It should be this way, but it doesn't work, how to correctly convert it?

--EDIT--

Since that wasn't working lets see if there is anything wrong with the rest of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include "SerialClass.h"    // Library described above
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool acabou(char str[]){
    for(int i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++){
        if(str[i]=='\n'){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main(){
    float x,y,z;
    char buffer[256] = "";
    Serial* SP = new Serial("\\\\.\\COM5");
    if (SP->IsConnected())
        printf("Conectado com sucesso\n");
    while(SP->IsConnected()){
        char incomingData[256] = "";
        int dataLength = 256;
        int readResult = 0;
        readResult = SP->ReadData(incomingData,dataLength);
        if(readResult!=-1){
            strcat(buffer,incomingData);
            if(acabou(incomingData)){
                printf("%s",buffer);
                sscanf(buffer,"%f %f %f\n",&x,&y,&z);
                cout << x << " " << y << " " << z << endl;
                strcpy(buffer,"");
            }
        }else if(acabou(incomingData)){
            printf("%s",buffer);
            sscanf(buffer,"%f %f %f\n",&x,&y,&z);
            cout << x << " " << y << " " << z << endl;
            strcpy(buffer,"");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just saying "it doesn't work" is a terrible description of the problem. How did you test? What results did you get? What results did you expect?

Comment: Is string a `char *`?

Comment: I print the value received in the screen, they are all 0 or something crazy, but no decimal value is received

Comment: Yes @Ben its a char *

Comment: It compiles and runs fine here: http://ideone.com/MWFq53

Comment: omg, what is wrong with my code then? '-', I'm starting to panic haha, BTW amazing site you sent, didn't knew of its existance

Comment: Let's be clear. You don't have multiple floats in a string. You have multiple real numbers represented in decimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code was right from the beginning, also *@user657267*'s code is working.

The problem was in my code, the string was coming with `,` as separator from decimal to integer of the variable, I made a simple function to change `,` to `.` and its working now.

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Stick with C++

```
std::istringstream iss{string};

float x{}, y{}, z{};

iss >> x >> y >> z;
```

That said, assuming `string` is of type `char const*` your code should work as-is.

Comment: Mind explain what is happening there?

Comment: @GuilhermeGarciadaRosa I'm not sure if anything I say can make the code clearer, what part do you not understand? This is very basic C++.

Comment: oh, I get it now haha, but why is the floats with brackets? {}

Comment: @GuilhermeGarciadaRosa I'm just in the habit of using uniform initialization, it's the same as writing `x = 0;`

Comment: its not working, my string is a char str[256]

Comment: @jww indeed, thanks for the correction!